# How to make a currency system in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've recently created a discord bot in python and wanted to add a currency system to it. I want to be able to store and recall the balance of each player.
Any tips on where to start or links to videos will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a system like this is my bot, I did it by storing my data in a JSON file. You can do this by simply creating a TXT file named data.txt and typing this inside. Also, be sure to import the JSON module.

```
{points: []}
```

Then in your python code, you can do something like this.

```
with open("data.txt") as json_file:
    points = json.load(json_file)

for user in points["points"]:
    if user["id"] == ctx.author.id:
        point_num = user["points"]

await ctx.send(f"You have {point_num} points")

with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(points, outfile)
```

And if you ever wanted to add points you could do something like this.

```
with open("data.txt") as json_file:
    points = json.load(json_file)

for user in points["points"]:
    if user["id"] == member.id:
        user["points"] += amount

with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(points, outfile)
```

You may run into problems like every user not having their own storage, so at the beginning of your setup, you should assign everyone their own storage like so.

```
with open("data.txt") as json_file:
    points = json.load(json_file)

for user in ctx.guild.members:
    points.append({
"id": member.id,
"points": 0    
})

with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(points, outfile)
```

This would ensure that everyone currently in the discord guild has their own storage. So you can now delete this code after running it once and making sure it saved to the TXT file. Now we should add some code that will make sure everyone new gets storage. So, create a new instance of the on_member_join event and put this inside.

```
with open("data.txt") as json_file:
    points = json.load(json_file)

points["points"].append({
    "id": member.id,
    "points": 0,
})

with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(points, outfile)
```

And you should be done! Sorry for this being such a long post, it's just that doing this sort of this takes time. Hopefully, you understood this and were able to successfully make your economic system. If you have any questions, go ahead and comment on this, don't worry I'll see it!