# Discord.py give command

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i am trying to make a point system with a give command, like if a user completes a challenge a mod can give the user points, i already made a function for it to write the users ID and 0 points into a .json when they join (first box) but i can't seem to get the give command correctly(second box), and no errors show up, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

```
async def update_data(users, user): #
    if not user.id in users: #i called this in the member join event
      users[user.id] = {}
      users[user.id]['points'] = 0
```

this function is supposed to add points:

```
async def add_points(ctx, users, user, pts): #I wrote that function at the beginning of the script
      users[user.id]['points'] += pts
```

and this is the give command:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
    async def give(ctx, member, amount):
      with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users =  json.load(f)
        await add_points(users, member, amount) 
      with open('users.json', 'w') as f:                      
        json.dump('users', 'f') 
      await ctx.send(f'given {member} {amount} programming points')
```

(sorry for the lack of info)

Answer (score 1):

If users is a list, you can’t just index it like a dictionary.

```
for user in users:
    if user[“id”] == member.id:
        user[“points”] += AMOUNT
```

You should have some form of ID with their user id.

This is all assuming your JSON file looks like this.

```
{“points”: []}
```

Comment: hello again @StarbuckBarista, i tried to do your suggestion but i can't figure it out! could you tell me if i'm doing something wrong? i will post the code in the next comment

Comment: ```@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def give(ctx, member, *, amount):
  async def add_points(users, member, amount): 
    for user in users:
      if user['id'] == member.id:
        user['programming_points'] += amount
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users =  json.load(f)
    await update_data(users, member)
    await add_points(users, member, amount) 
  with open('users.json', 'w') as f:     
    json.dump('users', 'f')```

Comment: `async def update_data(users, user):
  if not user.id in users:
    users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['programming_points'] = []`

Comment: You should check out my other post on making a currency system . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625197/how-to-make-a-currency-system-in-discord-py/63626293#63626293

Comment: thank you very much, i will check it out soon and if it's ok i'll update you to see if it works